# function in python to loop through columns and replace values if condition is met

Tags: pandas, function, for-loop

I want to create a function that evaluates columns A-C. If row value is Type, immediately followed by A,B,C then a replace the value in those columns with "". If a value is replaced, I want to create a column named "Replaced"=1.

Below is the code to create the df and the function that I wrote. I am wondering what I am doing wrong in this function?  Can someone help me, please?

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                    'ID': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
                    'Values': [57, 98, 87, 69, 98],
                    'A': ['Type', 'Type', 'Type', 'Type', 'Type'],
                    'B': ['A', 'B', 'Type', 'Type', 'Type'],
                    'C': ['B', 'B','A', 'Type', 'C']
            }
    )
df





#function I wrote:
cols=['A','B','C']
def fix_type(self):
    for i in range(len(cols) - 1):
        if cols[i] == 'Type' and cols[i+1] in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
            cols[i] = ''
            cols[i+1] = ''
            Replaced = 1

df[cols].apply(fix_type)
df
```

The function above does not give the result I was intending. The result would look like this: As mentioned above, if Type is followed by A, B,C, I would like to #replace "Type" and subsequent A/B/C with "".

```
df_result=pd.DataFrame(
            {
                    'ID': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
                    'Values': [57, 98, 87, 69, 98],
                    'A': ['', '', 'Type', 'Type', 'Type'],
                    'B': ['', '','', 'Type', ''],
                    'C': ['B', 'B','', 'Type', ''],
                    'Replaced': [1, 1,1,0, 1]
            }
    )

df_result
```

Comment: You should explain the expected output. Not clear why the second row becomes `'','','B'`.

Comment: I hope my comment clarified it. I want to replace rows where type is immediately followed by A,B or C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**) With custom replacement function:

```
def replace_type_pair(s):
    abc_cols = s[:-1]   # (A, B, C) columns
    idx = ((abc_cols.eq('Type') & abc_cols.shift(-1).isin(abc_cols.index))
            .values.nonzero()[0])   # index of 'Type' value conditioned
    if idx.size:
        s[idx[0]: idx[0] + 2] = ''  # reset 'Type' and the value next to it
        s['Replaced'] = 1
    return s

df['Replaced'] = 0
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Replaced']
df.loc[:, cols] = (df[cols].apply(replace_type_pair, axis=1))
print(df)
```

---

```
  ID  Values     A     B     C  Replaced
0  1      57                 B         1
1  2      98                 B         1
2  3      87  Type                     1
3  4      69  Type  Type  Type         0
4  5      98  Type                     1
```

---

Or

**2**) With boolean mask and traversal on matched rows basing on preliminary found/calculated indices:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df['Replaced'] = 0
m = (df[cols].eq('Type', axis=1) & df[cols].shift(-1, axis=1).isin(cols))
idx = np.argwhere(m.values)
df.loc[idx[:, 0], 'Replaced'] = 1
for row, col in idx:
    df.loc[row, cols[col: col + 2]] = ''
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you! Being new to python, I learned something new.

Comment: @user3641630, welcome, check my second approach, it could be more efficient for you

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution :

```
tmp = df[cols]
N = 1 # "OP: immediately followed"
m1 = tmp.mask(tmp.eq("Type")).bfill(axis=1, limit=N).isnull()
m2 = tmp.shift(axis=1, fill_value="Type").ne("Type")

out = (
    df[df.columns.difference(cols)].join(tmp.where(m1|m2, ""))
        .assign(Replaced=(~(m1^m2).all(axis=1)).astype(int))
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  ID  Values     A     B     C  Replaced
0  1      57                 B         1
1  2      98                 B         1
2  3      87  Type                     1
3  4      69  Type  Type  Type         0
4  5      98  Type                     1
```